# Ubuntu Software Center doesn't start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I installed Ubuntu in a Google Cloud's VM, but there is a problem: when I start Ubuntu Software Center it doesn't open.  When I click on Applications and after I click on Ubuntu Software Center, the mouse'indicator is in loop.

[image: bad Software Center]

And the program doesn't open.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Start it on the command line and edit the output from the console into your question.

Comment: Also show the output of command `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy What sense would that make?

Comment: @Pikachu95 Please provide more info on what Ubuntu version and what all your steps prior your mentionned problem were. How did you create the VM? What are the VMs features? Do you have any info on the graphical specs of your VM? Do programs other than `Ubuntu Software Center` start without problems? Can you provide info on the system load, like RAM, CPU use, etc.?

Comment: sudo software center: file.io/CdMagy

Comment: sudo apt-get update: file.io/Gofra4

Comment: @Socrates: I created VM with Ubuntu 14. About graphical specs I don't use advance graphical card (because I need to upgrade account and graphical card doesn't cheap). I've same problem with Firefox browser, but with others programs (for example office) I haven't this problem. RAM is 5 GB, CPU is Intel Haswell and number of CPU is 1.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `software-center`. What's the terminal output?

Comment: I answered. The output that I uploaded is here: file.io/CdMagy

Comment: I cannot see the output from the links you have provided. Have you tried to uninstall it and then re-install? To uninstall Ubuntu Software Center, run the following commands from a Terminal:
$sudo apt-get remove software-center $sudo apt-get autoremove software-center 
Tor reinstall it, run the following commands in the Terminal:
$sudo apt-get update $sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04/1294015#1294015?newreg=3a43e218ba2f45bb868fff6f8cc8b855 for some detailed answers.